# using integer variable to image name in ios

Tags: ios, variables, for-loop, integer, imageview

I have a set of images named `0.png`, `1.png`, `2.png`, etc...

Say I only have five. I want to use an integer variable (infoInt) to determine what image is displayed. Since I'm naming the images in numbers, I though I could define the image as what ever the integer was. i.e. infoInt.png (as infoInt changes). I'm not sure how I can approach it. Here is my attempt.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];
UIImage *img;

for (infoInt =0; infoInt<=5; infoInt++) {
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:infoInt".png"]; //What to do here? How do I use infoInt variable in image name?
    [imageView setImage:img];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` to construct the name, as in

```
img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", infoInt]];
```

Comment: Hey thanks, the code definitely makes sense. But all the images seem to be displaying the one image, where infoInt = 5. I was hoping it was going to assign an integer for each increment. Is there a way I can increment the integer after assigning infoInt to an image.

Comment: @AdrianFarfan: You're assigning all the images, in turn, to the same imageview. Of course it's going to end up only displaying the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
img = [UIImage imageNamed:infoInt".png"];
```

to

```
img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",infoInt]];
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can use stringWithFormat and use the for loop counter to generate image name as

```
img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", infoInt]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", infoInt]
img = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
```

Also refer [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for more string functions.